# Salesforce Connect with Cross-Org Adapter: This session is not valid for use with the REST API

Tags: oauth2, authentication, salesforce-connect

I am using Salesforce Connect with a cross-org adapter to connect two orgs.

I have configured the external data source with oAuth and an Authentication Provider. The data source was successfully created but when I try to Validate and Sync data, it is throwing me the following error :

> We encountered an unexpected error. Try again later, or contact your
>   administrator, who can verify the external data source settings and
>   the external system's availability. Error received from the external
>   system: This session is not valid for use with the REST API

Comment: Is this the Salesforce Connect cross-org adapter? If so, it is either a product bug or the user account you are using when setting up the data source does not have enough privileges in the target org. Either way, you're better off opening a ticket with Salesforce customer support.

Comment: @identigral yes it is a cross org adapter. The user that I am using is a standard System admin profile, so it has all the required privileges. Let me try and create a ticket with salesforce.

Comment: Did you get any response from Salesforce support? If yes, please provide an answer here

Comment: @Madhurima I have faced the very same problem, please provide the answer if SFDC Support replied to you

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add "Manage user data via APIs (api)" to the OAuth scopes in your External Org's OAuth settings in the Connected App.

Answer (score -1):

Add scope "api refresh_token" while setting up External Data Sources in your source org. Make sure You also added "Manage user data via APIs (api)" to the OAuth scopes in your External Org's OAuth Settings in connected App.